# Hartl Tutorial 3.1: 500 Runtime Error when navigating to 'home' static page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing, static-pages

I'm extremely new to coding in general - so be gentle.

I'm on Chapter 3, 3.1, in the very end after creating the `static_pages`, home and help, by entering `$ rails generate controller StaticPages home help`, I cannot then navigate to the page without getting a corresponding 500 Runtime Error, which in turn `Killed` the running server.

The "hello" app works just fine and I've had no issues up until now.

Notes: I am following the tutorial on a Windows 7 x64, but I'm taking Hartl's recommendation to use the Cloud IDE with Git, Bitbucket, and Heroku. I did have to run Rails 4.2.1 instead of Rails 4.2.2 however due to an issue when first starting out.

What could I be doing wrong? Please let me know if I need to include any more information, this is all very new to me.

EDIT:

I checked my files again what @Rich Peck stated and theyre all the same except the `Routes.rb` file which only has this (which was generated by the system, I'm also omitting all # comments):

`Rails.application.routes.draw do
   get 'static_pages/home'
   get 'static_pages/help'
   root 'application#hello'
 end`

Ive also pulled my logs as stated by a few comments, and this is the result of the last 100 lines:

`2015-10-11T21:25:49.589384+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run`rails server -h`for more startup options
    2015-10-11T21:25:49.589385+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    2015-10-11T21:25:49.589386+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 208.115.151.20 at 2015-10-11 21:25:49 +0000
    2015-10-11T21:25:49.646987+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ApplicationController#hello as HTML
    2015-10-11T21:25:49.656139+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
    2015-10-11T21:25:49.655832+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered text template (0.0ms)
    2015-10-11T21:25:49.786454+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mysterious-journey-1439.herokuapp.com request_id=2474855b-e5c5-4db8-8b2a-83f0d6095d2d fwd="208.115.151.20" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=228
    2015-10-11T21:25:49.658965+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mysterious-journey-1439.herokuapp.com request_id=e85687fc-6820-42c1-b389-4a6d8e0e2ffa fwd="208.115.151.20" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=73ms status=304 bytes=397
    2015-10-11T21:59:04.638018+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
    2015-10-11T21:59:04.638730+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
    2015-10-11T21:59:04.639573+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.575098+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.991420+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 21:59:06] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.991427+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in`select'
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.991429+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.991431+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in`start'
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.991432+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.991433+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in`run'
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.991434+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.991436+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in`start'
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.991438+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.991440+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in`tap'
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.991441+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.991442+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.991443+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.991445+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in`require'
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.991446+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.991478+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 21:59:06] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.991452+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 21:59:06] INFO  going to shutdown ...
    2015-10-11T21:59:06.991498+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
    2015-10-11T21:59:07.767999+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
    2015-10-11T21:59:08.554265+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command`bin/rails server -p 21794 -e production
    `2015-10-11T21:59:12.579369+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 21:59:12] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
    2015-10-11T21:59:12.579406+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 21:59:12] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
    2015-10-11T21:59:12.579784+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 21:59:12] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=21794
    2015-10-11T21:59:13.087410+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2015-10-11T22:34:07.204262+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
    2015-10-11T22:34:07.204981+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
    2015-10-11T22:34:10.871115+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813473+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 22:34:11] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813479+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in`select'
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813483+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813484+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in`start'
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813486+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813487+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in`run'
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813489+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813490+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in`start'
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813492+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813493+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in`tap'
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813495+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813497+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813498+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813500+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in`require'
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813501+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813508+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 22:34:11] INFO  going to shutdown ...
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813551+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 22:34:11] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813591+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813594+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run`rails server -h`for more startup options
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813593+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:21794
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813598+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
    2015-10-11T22:34:11.813596+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    2015-10-11T22:34:12.863144+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
    2015-10-11T22:59:27.859347+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
    2015-10-11T22:59:27.859754+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
    2015-10-11T22:59:31.767799+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command`bin/rails server -p 43789 -e production
    `2015-10-11T22:59:35.850425+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 22:59:35] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
    2015-10-11T22:59:35.850445+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 22:59:35] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
    2015-10-11T22:59:35.850845+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 22:59:35] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=43789
    2015-10-11T22:59:36.187808+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2015-10-11T22:59:36.930155+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
    2015-10-11T22:59:36.930162+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:43789
    2015-10-11T22:59:36.930163+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run`rails server -h`for more startup options
    2015-10-11T22:59:36.930165+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    2015-10-11T22:59:36.963421+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ApplicationController#hello as HTML
    2015-10-11T22:59:36.930166+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 208.115.151.20 at 2015-10-11 22:59:36 +0000
    2015-10-11T22:59:36.971478+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
    2015-10-11T22:59:36.974594+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mysterious-journey-1439.herokuapp.com request_id=b8fe0c84-e45c-4997-be06-9742f276fb98 fwd="208.115.151.20" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=47ms status=304 bytes=397
    2015-10-11T22:59:36.971195+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered text template (0.0ms)
    2015-10-11T22:59:37.155800+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mysterious-journey-1439.herokuapp.com request_id=ce175e20-0e6c-40e1-9e4e-ec842143c159 fwd="208.115.151.20" dyno=web.1 connect=16ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=228
    2015-10-11T23:35:06.014571+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
    2015-10-11T23:35:06.015165+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
    2015-10-11T23:35:08.748838+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2015-10-11T23:35:09.396823+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 23:35:09] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
    2015-10-11T23:35:09.396829+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in`select'
    2015-10-11T23:35:09.396831+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
    2015-10-11T23:35:09.396833+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in`start'
    2015-10-11T23:35:09.396834+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
    2015-10-11T23:35:09.396835+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in`run'
    2015-10-11T23:35:09.396838+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
    2015-10-11T23:35:09.396836+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in`start'
    2015-10-11T23:35:09.396843+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    2015-10-11T23:35:09.396840+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in`block in server'
    2015-10-11T23:35:09.396846+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
    2015-10-11T23:35:09.396847+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in`'
    2015-10-11T23:35:09.396842+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    2015-10-11T23:35:09.396841+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in`tap'
    2015-10-11T23:35:09.396844+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    2015-10-11T23:35:09.396853+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 23:35:09] INFO  going to shutdown ...
    2015-10-11T23:35:09.396894+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
    2015-10-11T23:35:09.396870+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 23:35:09] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
    2015-10-11T23:35:10.254851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
WARNING: Toolbelt v3.42.17 update available.`

Comment: What does your heroku log say? From the console, `heroku logs` to see the last 100 lines.

Comment: Also, you'd do well to post your `routes.rb` file. You didn't indicate whether you set up any routes that map to the methods of your `static_pages_controller`.

Comment: Please post your `app/controllers/static_controller` and routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm extremely new to coding

Because you're new, I'll give you a breakdown of how I'd **debug** this. It may not be an answer in itself, but it should at least help you out.

---

Firstly, you need to make sure you have the right `controller` and `views` set up.

The main problem for many new coders is they will blindly follow a tutorial and then be unable to understand *what is being done*. I know what it's like because I do it all the time (when learning something new)..

Thus, you need to understand *what* is being added to your app, and how it should behave:

---

**1. Controller**

Your first port of call is the *controller*.

You can [read more about this here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate).

Rails will have created:

```
#app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
   def hello
   end

   def help
   end
end
```

This, although not strictly adhering to the [`CRUD`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) setup you'll use later in Rails, should give you at least the ability to call these two actions.

You must first check if you have the above file.

---

**2. Views**

Secondly, you need to look at the views you've had generated.

These will be located at:

```
#app/views/static_pages/hello.html.erb
#app/views/static_pages/help.html.erb
```

Both of these will provide functionality to allow you to *view* your controller action outputs. They're not critical to the debug process at this time.

They should really have nothing inside them.

---

**3. Routes**

Finally, you want to look at your *routes*.

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :static_pages, only: [], path: "" do
   collection do
     get :hello #-> url.com/hello
     get :help #-> url.com/help
   end 
end
```

This will give you the ability to access the controller actions, and by virtue, the views that you have just generated.

All of these should work together, without any data, to provide access to `url.com/hello` and `url.com/help`.

---

[image]
<sub>(source: [asciicasts.com](http://asciicasts.com/system/photos/232/original/E187I01.png))</sub>

[**500 Errors**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) are basically saying your *server* has an error.

What errors on the server might cause the 500 issue?

Mostly, it's due to calling variables which don't exist...

```
#app/views/static_pages/hello.html.erb
<%= @hello %>
```

If you're using `Heroku`, the best way to debug - as with standard Rails - is to look at the console. In standard rails, the console is visible on your screen (most of the time); with Heroku, it's slightly different.

Heroku logs are strange because they don't format very well in Windows. We tend to use [`LogEntries`](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/logentries) with the "live" functionality to see what's going on, and correct it:

[image]

Browsing through these logs will show you what the error is, and thus give you some perspective on how to fix it.

--

Finally, you *may* wish to use a gem such as [`better_errors`](https://github.com/BetterErrors/better_errors) or [`exception_handler`](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler)

Comment: All my files are the same except the "routes.rb" file which only has this:

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'static_pages/home'
  get 'static_pages/help'